# Can't get this Java program to work

Tags: java

Okay changed the code a bit, but the program still doesn't work properly. I want to be able to enter type of product (fruit) in the java console when program is run, enter any type of fruit (bananas, apples or oranges) and then enter a qty.

```
import java.util.*;

public class demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String str[] = { "Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges" };
    double price[] = { 2.09, 2.59, 2.25 };
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter type of product: ");
    String string = sc.nextLine();
    if ("fruit".equals(string)) {
        while (i < str.length) {
            while (j < price.length) {
                System.out.print(str[i++] + ": " + "£" + (price[j++]) + "p per bag \n");

            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("Enter which type of " + string + ": ");

    String string1 = sc.nextLine();

    boolean strs = "bananas".equals(string1);
    boolean strs1 = "apples".equals(string1);
    boolean strs2 = "oranges".equals(string1);
    if (strs) {
        System.out.print("Enter qty of " + str[0] + " (by bag): ");
    }

    if (strs1) {
        System.out.print("Enter qty of " + str[1] + " (by bag): ");

    }
    if (strs2) {
        System.out.print("Enter qty of " + str[2] + " (by bag): ");
    }

    int qty = sc.nextInt();
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int h = 1;
    if ((a[h] == (qty)) && (strs) || (strs1) || (strs2)){
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print(qty + " bag(s) of " + string1 + " have been added to your basket, " + "total costing £"
                + (qty) * price[0] + "p");

        }
    }   
}
```

Any more ideas?

Comment: What does the error exactly say?

Comment: I put a catch Exception e, which allowed me to out print my own error message (if that makes sense)

Comment: String string = sc.next("fruit"); is in error fix this

Comment: You want to print e, not ignore it just to print error.  You can either put e in the print message or use e.printstacktrace(). This will give you more information as to what’s going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistake is Reading strings.

Replace

```
String string = sc.next("fruit");          // Line 17
String string1 = sc.next("bananas");       // Line 26
String string2 = sc.next("apples");        // Line 30
String string3 = sc.next("oranges");       // Line 35
```

With

```
String string = sc.nextLine();             // Line 17
String string1 = sc.nextLine();            // Line 26
String string2 = sc.nextLine();            // Line 30
String string3 = sc.nextLine();            // Line 35
```

If you want to check the `String` entered , then make use of following code:-

```
if(string.equals("fruit")){ 
   // statements
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is at String string = sc.next("fruit"); either change it to sc.nextLine()  or Something like below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

String str[] = { "Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges" };
double stk[] = { 1.09, 1.59, 1.25 };
int i = 0;
int j =0;

try {
    System.out.print("Enter type of product: ");
    String string = sc.next();

    while (i < str.length) {
        while (j < stk.length) {
        System.out.print(str[i++] + ": " + "£" + (stk[j++]) + "p per bag \n");

        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("Enter which type of "+string+": ");
    String string1 = sc.next();
    if(string1 != null) {
        System.out.print("Enter qty of "+string1+ "(per bag) \n");
    } 
    String string2 = sc.next();     
    if(string2 != null) {
            System.out.print("Enter qty of " +string2+ "(in lbs) \n");

    } 
    String string3 = sc.next();
    if (string3 != null) {
            System.out.print("Enter qty of " +string3+ "(in lbs) \n");

    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Eror");
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `InputMismatchException` that, according to the JavaDoc, is

> thrown by a `Scanner` to indicate that the token retrieved does not
>   match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of
>   range for the expected type.

So if you don't write `"fruit"` as you requested (`String string = sc.next("fruit")`), the execution terminates with that exception. So, **to fix your code, you should replace**

```
String string = sc.next("fruit");
```

**with something like**

```
String string = sc.nextLine();
if ("fruit".equalsIgnoreCase(string)) { /* design your control flow as you want */
```

You can apply the same rule to the other `sc.next()` present in your code.

A side note: **never swallow exceptions into a `catch` block; always log them.**

Comment: Obviusly you have to adjust the logic of the code according with your needs; I added a `if` only to demonstrate that you can design the flow you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your scanning of input line is wrong.To scan input data in Java you should use

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = in.nextInt(); // To input integer
char ch = in.nextChar(); // To input character
String str = in.nextLine(); // To get a complete line of input
String s = in.next(); //To get a single string
```

Replace your inputing line according to the above given.

Cheers :)